# Bootstrap: move text to the side of Checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4, text-alignment

I'm trying to get the "Default checkbox" to be at the side of the checkbox

[checkbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eB2sn.jpg)

what i have so far

```
<div class="col-2">
     <label for="Desc" class="col-sm col-form-label">Default Checkbox

      </label>
     <div class="col pr-0">
          <input type="checkbox" readonly id="defcheck" name="defcheck" class="form-control form-control-sm"
       data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" size="2"> 
         <br />
                                    
      </div>
</div>
```

Tried to just move the label tag below the input type but that did not work

Answer (score 2):

Use below code.

```
<div class="col-6">
     <div class="col pr-0" style="display: flex;">
          <input type="checkbox" readonly="" id="defcheck" name="defcheck" class="form-control form-control-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" size="2" style="width: auto;"> 
          <label for="Desc" class="col-sm col-form-label" style="padding: 12px;">Default Checkbox</label>
      </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-2">
     <div class="col pr-0">
            <label for="Desc" class="col-sm col-form-label">Default Checkbox</label>
          <input type="checkbox" readonly id="defcheck" name="defcheck" class="form-control form-control-sm"
   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" size="2"> 
         <br />
      </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="col-2">
     <div class="col pr-0">
          <input type="checkbox" readonly id="defcheck" name="defcheck" class="form-control form-control-sm"
   data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" size="2"> 
    <label for="Desc" class="col-sm col-form-label">Default Checkbox</label>

      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Code only answers do not read well and are therefore not good answers. Please add some supporting text that clarifies exactly what your code is doing and how it answers the question.